# Validar datos en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Validar datos y personalizar el mensaje desde el controlador

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el problema? ¿qué es lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

[Mensajes de error personalizados](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-error-messages)

Si es necesario, puede usar mensajes de error personalizados para la validación en lugar de los valores predeterminados.  Hay varias formas de especificar mensajes personalizados.  Primero, puede pasar los mensajes personalizados como tercer argumento al método `Validator::make`. Aunque en tu caso, como estás usando un atajo, sería el segundo argumento.

```php
$messages = [
    'nombre.required' => 'necesitamos que ingrese el nombre!',
];

$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required',
 ], $messages);
```

En este caso, se especifica un mensaje personalizado para un atributo dado (`nombre`). Especifique primero el nombre del atributo, seguido de la regla

Puedes ver otras opciones en la documentación, revisa el link.